# How to slow down scrolling in the mail list in Outlook (.exe) to one line per mouse wheel notch

Tags: microsoft-outlook, mouse, scrolling

The mouse is already set to one line per mouse notch in the Windows Control Panel settings. Nevertheless (and only in Outlook), the mail list scrolls three lines per notch. Moreover, the scrolling is jumpy and not smooth. Orientation in the mail list is almost impossible this way.

Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: There are reports of this problem only happening when the reading pane is on the bottom. If yours is truly on the bottom, try moving it to the right to see if the problem disappears.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my test, i found that when you turn off reading pane or when the reading pane is on the bottom, as harrymc mentioned, the issue occurs. I'm afraid that it's by design.

To make the mail list scrolls on lines per notch, just turn on reading pane to right.
[image]